# How do I query user registry settings on a remote machine?

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, registry

Supposing that I have a remote machine on which I'm an admin, and I want to query some values in the windows registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` for a given user on a given machine. (The user may be logged in or off.)

Is it possible to query HKCU like this? And, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the user's SID (Security Identifier) and query `HKEY_USERS\{SID}`